# Query Help - Matching Stage and returning the most recent one

Tags: sql

The code below show students with multiple candidacies but not their current one. Students cannot have more than one candidacy for the same year, term, and division, so this is to target them so that I can mass delete them.

I need to add in code that will only target the highest stage. If stages match, it will take the one with the most recent date (hist_stage_dte). I need assistance. Greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT * 
FROM candidacy
WHERE ( candidacy.yr_cde = '2017' ) AND  
     ( candidacy.trm_cde = '20' ) AND  
     ( candidacy.div_cde like 'g%' ) and
     (candidacy.CUR_CANDIDACY = 'n') and
     (candidacy.ID_NUM in (SELECT candidacy.id_num     
                           FROM candidacy  
                           WHERE ( candidacy.yr_cde = '2017' ) AND  
                                 ( candidacy.trm_cde = '20' ) AND  
                                 ( candidacy.div_cde like 'g%' )   
                           GROUP BY candidacy.id_num 
                           HAVING count(candidacy.id_num) > 1))
```

Comment: What SQL server are you using? MySQL/Postres/MSSQL/....? Do you need to delete everything with the same ID_NUM where it has more than one record and leave only the most recent one?

Answer (score 1):

try pickup the record by ROW_NUMBER function. To use the row number in where clause, make a second sub query.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NUM ORDER BY hist_stage_dte DESC) as ROW_NUM, *
    FROM candidacy
    WHERE ( candidacy.yr_cde = '2017' ) AND  
          ( candidacy.trm_cde = '20' ) AND  
          ( candidacy.div_cde like 'g%' ) and
          (candidacy.CUR_CANDIDACY = 'n') and
          (candidacy.ID_NUM in (SELECT candidacy.id_num     
                                FROM   candidacy  
                                WHERE ( candidacy.yr_cde = '2017' ) AND  
                                      ( candidacy.trm_cde = '20' ) AND  
                                      ( candidacy.div_cde like 'g%' )   
                                GROUP BY candidacy.id_num 
                                HAVING count(candidacy.id_num) > 1)) 
    ) TB_AUX
    WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. May I ask what TB_AUX is? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user8452670 ,  **TB_AUX** is a **alias** for the dynamic table. You can use any other name for the alias.